# jQuery dataTables - Custom Filtering Based On Original Row Data

Tags: javascript, datatables

JSBin: http://live.datatables.net/nujehixu/3/edit?js,console,output

```
$(document).ready( function () {

  // push our custom filter onto the stack of filters
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter) {
    // get filter value
    var value = $("#example_filter > label > input").val().toLowerCase();
    // check filter value against original row data
    var original = rowData[1].toLowerCase();
    console.log(original);
    return original.indexOf(value) > -1;
  });

  function addEllipsis(original, charLimit) {
    if (original.length > charLimit) {
      // substring the original and add ellipsis with a title attribute of the original
      return '<div title="' + original + '">' + original.substr(0, charLimit) + '&hellip;' + '</div>';
    }
    // return the original value since it is already short enough
    return '<div title="' + original + '">' + original + '</div>';
  }

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: 1,
        render: function (data, type, row) {
          // render with ellipsis if necessary
          return addEllipsis(data, 6);
        }
      }
    ]
  });
} );
```

Check out the linked example, I'm trying to use a custom filter based on the original row data, but the issue surfaces when entering a filter value like `systems`. The rows with Systems Administrator are filtered out when I would expect `systems` to match 'Systems Administrator' and show those rows.

Reading through the [source](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L2937), it looks like there is a [global filter](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L3033) applied first against a search string, which is [compiled from the rendered values](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L3068).

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean filtered out wrongly?

Comment: @OlaviSau, I mean that I would expect systems to match Systems Administrator and show that row, this is not the case. I'll edit to make that more clear.

Comment: @JayTaggart - Have edited the code into the question. You should really include some code in a question, especially when the question is about some specific code not working.  A link does not help future visitors to recognise the problem and no one can be sure that your link will persists or expire in 3 days, 3 months or 3 years.

Comment: @davidkonrad, makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the default search still is performed, and by that it cannot find any matches to "systems" since the values of the columns is rendered to "system...". You can do it like this :

```
$("#example_filter > label > input").unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
  // push our custom filter onto the stack of filters
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter) {
    // get filter value
    // check filter value against original row data
    var original = rowData[1].toLowerCase();
    console.log(original);
    return original.indexOf(value) > -1; 
  });
  table.draw();
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
})
```

altered code -> **http://live.datatables.net/dalesexe/4/edit**

---

A better answer is to return different values from `render()` based on `type` that can be `_`, `filter` or `display`. On `display` return the ellipsied' value, otherwise return the original value. By that you can skip the custom filter entirely :

```
render: function (data, type, row) {
             switch (type) {
               case 'display' : 
                 return addEllipsis(data, 6); break;
               default :
                 return data; break;  
             }             
        }
```

new code -> **http://live.datatables.net/dalesexe/6/edit**

Comment: The problem with this is that you lose all filtering except for the specific cases you code. For example, if you want to search for a specific name, you would have to code in some logic to check rowData[0]. Ideally, I would like to keep default behavior and augment it with my logic.

Comment: I'm going to upvote this as it does solve the immediate problem, but I would still like to see if there is a better answer. If I don't have anything better in 24 hours, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @JayTaggart - see update, there is a better answer, or at least better solution - I was just focusing on getting your custom filter to work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your charlimit cuts the characters and your matching with the displayed data not the original data. Basically `systems` can't be found because `system` is the maximum length.

Comment: If you look at my function though, I look at the original data and it is Systems Administrator. I've updated to include a console.log

Comment: I tried adding +1 to the substring and it worked then :O

Comment: Where does the rowdata come from?

Comment: rowData is being passed in via datatables and corresponds to the original data for the row, not the rendered data.